# I need to get a list of com ports and then listen to each one

Tags: javascript, node-serialport

There is a code that should get a list of COM ports, and then go through each port and get the value returned by the device connected to the port

```
let portsPathes = [];

SerialPort.SerialPort.list().then((ports)=>{
    ports.forEach(port=>{
        portsPathes.push(port.path);
    });
    ports.close();
});
let datas = [];
portsPathes.forEach(portPath=>{
    let port = new SerialPort.SerialPort({
        path: portPath,
    baudRate: 9600,
    dataBits: 8,
    parity: 'none',
    stopBits: 1,
    flowControl: false
    });
    //port.close();
    //port.setMaxListeners(10000);
    //port.pipe(new ReadlineParser.ReadlineParser({delimiter: '\r\n'}));
    //parser.once('data', data=>{console.log(data);});
});
```

When executing this code, I get an error

```
node:internal/process/promises:288
           triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
           ^

Error: Opening COM9: Access denied
Emitted 'error' event on SerialPort instance at:
    at SerialPort._error (C:\Users\1\Desktop\neft\andurino-callback\node_modules\
@serialport\stream\dist\index.js:78:18)
    at C:\Users\1\Desktop\neft\andurino-callback\node_modules\@serialport\stream\
dist\index.js:111:18
```

The same thing happens if you transfer the creation of SerialPort to forEach in the SerialPort.list()